# classmethod as self-creating object constructor

Tags: python

'm working with code to manage objects on a remote store, which means I can either create objects as the result of a read from the store, or create objects which are sent to the store at creation time. The real goal here is to only create objects when the representation of the object on the remote store exists - if there's no representation on the remote store, no object gets created.

```
class myClass:
  def __init__(self, parameter1, parameter2)
    self.param1 = parameter1
    self.param2 = parameter2

  @classmethod
  def create(parameter1, parameter2):
    if SendToRemoteStore(parameter1, parameter2) == True:
      return myClass(parameter1, parameter2)
    else:
      return None

  def __del__():
    DeleteFromRemoteStore(self)

# Two ways to create an instance
# As the result of a remote read:
data = GetFromRemoteStore()
object1 = myClass(data['foo'], data['bar'])

# Or if I'm creating the object here and 
# need to save it to store on creation:
object2 = myClass.create('baz', 'bar')
```

Comment: Also: Don't rely on `__del__` for anything relevant - explicitly dispose objects when you're done with them, perhaps add a [context manager](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/contextlib/) for convenience and raise a warning in `__del__` if something wasn't disposed normally.

Comment: Heh, I somehow left off the question part of the question - which was really "am I Doing It Wrong?"

Comment: Usually your local object act as proxies to remote objects, so the local Proxy should `raise ConnectionError` or so when the remote object does not exist. You could look at [Twisted's perspective broker](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/pb-intro.html) for some design inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

No need.

```
class myClass(object):
  def __new__(cls, parameter1, parameter2):
    if SendToRemoteStore(parameter1, parameter2):
      return super(myClass, cls).__new__(cls)
    else:
      return None

  def __init__(self, parameter1, parameter2):
    self.param1 = parameter1
    self.param2 = parameter2

  def __del__(self):
    DeleteFromRemoteStore(self)
```

Comment: The `else` clause isn't necessary.

Comment: @Robin: "Explicit is better than implicit."

Comment: I'm not sure returning `None` from `__new__` will do what you want.

Comment: @doublep: Have you looked at the code sample in the question?

Comment: @Ignacio: I don't think returning `None` falls under that adage.

Comment: @Robin: It does if you let the function do it implicitly instead.

Comment: @Ignacio: I disagree, but let's not have this discussion --- especially not here and now.